# understanding broadleaf extension and ui

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I am very new to broadleaf . I have some questions around the same ,ap per my knowledge In broadleaf we have 2 apps admin and the client app . I was just wondering if we have any extending ability of core broadleaf or any ability given by broadleaf to write own functionality

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own functionality. If you have seen demo site, it has 3 sub projects admin, core, site. As per its documentation

admin - has code related to admin functionality like adding and managing product catalog

site - has code to present product catalog and offers with checkout and payment to user

core -  has code which is common to both admin and site module.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Broadleaf can be made in different ways.

1. Because it uses spring you can replace actual beans with your implementation of some service for example ( or dao etc )
2. Also there are some extension points, you can see for example *org.broadleafcommerce.core.extension.ExtensionManager* and it's implementation and you can find points where you might add custom validation to cart for example. ( you can even change the controller). see  *org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.service.UpdateCartServiceExtensionManager*  as an example
3. Broadleaf has some concept of workflow that contains many Activities : *org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.Activity* that are handled by sequential Processors : *org.broadleafcommerce.core.workflow.SequenceProcessor* .For example you could see  *org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.service.workflow.add.ValidateAddRequestActivity* that has the role of validating add order item to cart.

If you want to find more tutorials you should read : http://docs.broadleafcommerce.org/core/current